# Aligned pointer

Tags: iphone, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What exactly is an 'aligned pointer' ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322926/what-exactly-is-an-aligned-pointer)

please give me the example of this statement:

A normal pointer type was implicitly cast to an aligned pointer type.

---

actually it is c language Question

Comment: pointers in asp.net? are you sure you have the correct tags?

Comment: Seeing as he also has "iphone", "jquery" and "objective-c as tags, I'm inclined to think no.

Comment: this question has already been answered. Please do not repost (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322926/what-exactly-is-an-aligned-pointer/4323044#4323044)

Comment: Please show the code that generates the error.

Comment: @Yanick Rochon: That is not the same question.  It was merely asking what an aligned pointer is.  This is asking what could cause a particular error message.

Comment: @JeremyP, the old question could have been amended with this very question : "And why should I get this message... ?" providing the compiler used also given. In short, this question should be closed IMO and his prior one should be detailed further.

Comment: @ Yanick Rochon: that would be changing the old question though.  The already given answers would then look incomplete and might attract down votes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can cast them.  Pointers which are aligned are *normal*.  You have to declare something as `__packed` to get it to be un-aligned.

You should read up on how the [ARM processor works.](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3544.html)    Alignment causes very quick memory access.  If you need things packed further, I recommend storing your data as a BLOB in a `NSData` or using a C-style byte[] array.

Also, see this [question/answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4074049/266252) and [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/979050/266252)